# Автозагрузка приложений windows и отключение файла из автозагрузки?

Tags: windows, реестр

Я кладу файл в папку автозагрузки для пользователя либо записываю ссылку в реестр и файл загружается при загрузке.
Если я зайду в Ccleaner или другое приложение для контроля автозагрузки и выключу автозагрузку моего приложения,то из папки автозагрузки оно не удалится,но запускаться не будет.
Где в реестре хранится метка,что данный файл не запускать?

Answer (score 1):

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved` Там `Run`, либо `Run32`.
Если загрузка включена, то стоит бинарное значение с большинством нулей `02 00 00 00...`. Если отключена, то система ставит другое значение, причем для каждого приложения уникальное. Как оно вычесляется, сказать не могу, ибо не знаю.
Начиная с 8.x версии Windows включать и отключать автозагрузку приложений можно в диспетчере задач, в соответствующей вкладке.